# Scanner isn't working - Prime Sieve. Code is finished

Tags: java, algorithm, java.util.scanner

I'm working on an arraylist implementation of PrimeSieve and I have all the code written but it seems to not run so I'm not sure if it's because the loops are bad or because I set up the scanner wrong.

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PrimeSieve {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     int inputNum;
     Scanner SL = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Pick a number to count up from:");
     inputNum = SL.nextInt();
     ArrayList<Boolean> BL = findPrime(inputNum);
     System.out.println("The prime numbers found:");
     for(int i = 0; i < inputNum; i++)
     {
         if(BL.get(i) == true)
         {
             System.out.println(i + ", ");
         }
     }
 }

 public static ArrayList<Boolean> findPrime(int maxNum)
 {
     ArrayList<Boolean> BL = new ArrayList<Boolean>();


     //Filling in the list.
     for(int i = 0; i < maxNum;  i++)
     {
         BL.add(true);

     }

     for(int i = 0; i * i <(maxNum); i++)
     {
         if(BL.get(i) == true)
         {
             for(int k = i*2; k < maxNum; k = k + i)
             {
                 BL.set(i, false);
             }
         }

     }
     return BL;


 }

}
```

Once I input any number and press enter, nothing works. My assumption would be that the program is constantly looping somewhere and it has to be broken.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Compile error? exception? just nothing happens? wrong result... ?

Comment: Did you type in anything (**and** hit ENTER)? I'm asking this, because you have not provided any example input and output.

Comment: Add some System.out.println() calls to the loops to make sure they're executed. Or use a debugger.

Comment: What's your input and output?

Comment: I would type something like 124 then enter then nothing, the cursor just blinks

Comment: The first time you get to `k = k + i` i is 0 so the loop is infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i * i < (maxNum); i++) {
    if (BL.get(i) == true) {
        for (int k = i * 2; k < maxNum; k = k + i) {
            BL.set(i, false);
        }
    }
}
```

First iteraction ( i = 0 )  :

```
for (int k = 0 * 2; k < maxNum; k = k + 0)
```

its like :

```
for (int k = 0 ; k < X ; k = k + 0 )
```

Fix it :)

About your problem ... it's easy guy ( use debug :) ):

```
for (int i = 2; i * i < (maxNum); i++) {
    if (BL.get(i) == true) {
        for (int k = i * 2; k < maxNum; k = k + i) {
            BL.set(k, false);
        }
    }

}
```

**Changes :**

```
int i = 2;
```

and

```
BL.set(k,false);
```

You must learn it by yourself :(

Comment: It's all fixed now but apparently, there's something wrong with my coding...Almost every entry in the list is coming out a prime.

Answer (score 4):

You have neverending for loop here:

```
for(int k = i*2; k < maxNum; k = k + i)
```

`i` is 0 and `k` is 0 so every step `k=0+0`

Comment: Yeap, this is the answer to the question, in addition BL.set(i,false) should be BL.set(k,false).

Comment: Damn it, I knew I was missing something. Thanks!

How do you suggest I fix this? I'm scratching my brain...